# Current flow in circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: e]

[image: ui]

I do not understand why the direction of I3 is to the right, I am supposed to find Vs which the solution is 36V, my only problem is the direction of current for kirchoff current law, so I would like to know why I1 and I2 are the direction they are.

Comment: It's a convention, that's all. Note that while the direction of I3 is to the right, its magnitude may or may not be positive...

Comment: If I use the opposite direction the voltage differential will be negative, and that will affect the kirchoff voltage law when calculating R2 voltage

Comment: Not if you keep track of the voltage polarity convention correctly (i.e. you need to change your voltage polarity conventions when you change your current direction convention, in order to always use the passive sign convention).